# Scrolling features in QGIS following field?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I have a lot of features with labels associated. Because some of this features are wrong placed, I have to scroll them all. Usually I work with the attribute table open and select every single feature and zoom at it.
This is a quite annoying process but it's the only way that I found for now. Anybody knows if there is a tool/plugin that permits to scroll all the features in a layer following a field (like the primary key field)?

The plugin ItemBrowser does something similar for what I'm looking for but it needs a selection of the items. Selection means that if I have to move only one feature I have to deselect all the others, move the feature, and then reselect all (not so efficient and could cause a lot of errors)